# FireHol overflowing logs

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I keep running into Firehol flooding my Syslog with messages like these.

```
Dec 21 23:28:24 ruby kernel: [397194.848618] PASS-unknown:IN=br0 OUT=eth4 MAC=<----some----> SRC=192.168.40.78 DST=x.x.x.x LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=60844 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51274 DPT=80 WINDOW=32940 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
Dec 21 23:30:54 ruby kernel: [397344.273426] IN-InetZiggo:IN=eth4 OUT= MAC=<----some----> SRC=71.192.24.195 DST=y.y.y.y LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=29253 PROTO=TCP SPT=52855 DPT=51300 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Dec 21 23:31:44 ruby kernel: [397394.815414] OUT-InetZiggo:IN= OUT=eth4 SRC=y.y.y.y DST=x.x.x.x LEN=132 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7530 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=993 DPT=35891 WINDOW=252 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0
```

Where x.x.x.x is valid IP on the internet, y.y.y.y my own IP and my lan is 192.168.40.0/24

I have Firehol configured like this, shortedend for brevity;

```
version 6

FIREHOL_LOG_MODE = "ULOG"
FIREHOL_LOG_LEVEL = "0"
```

and the interface like this;

```
interface eth4 InetZiggo
        policy drop
        server all reject
        server SSH              accept
        server dns              accept

        client  all             accept

interface br0 Bridge
        client all      accept
        server all      accept


router br2internet inface br0 outface eth4
        masquerade
        client all      accept
        server all      accept
```

So I would expect not to see those log messages, but I just can't get rid of them. They are correctly droppped or accepted far as I can see. The first entry is a lan machine connecting to a website, why would that be logged? Am I missing something? This never occured in Version 5.

Concrete question; why is Firehol logging these, what do they mean, and if they are harmless, how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

FireHOL, by default, logs all packets that the linux connection tracker thinks are not part of any connection and also are not matched by any rule in your firewall.

The kernel connection tracker keeps a list of all active connections. Packets that are part of existing connections are marked as `ESTABLISHED`. Packets that are not part of existing connections are marked as `NEW`.

In many cases, the connection tracker cleans this list before receiving the relative packets. In such cases, packets that were, a few milliseconds ago, part of existing connections (`ESTABLISHED`), now are not (and they appear as `NEW`).

These `NEW` packets that are not matched by the firewall rules, are logged by FireHOL.

To get rid of `TCP ACK+FIN` logs (the TCP connection closed message), set this at the top of firehol.conf:

```
FIREHOL_DROP_ORPHAN_TCP_ACK_FIN=1
```

To get rid of `INVALID` logs, set this:

```
FIREHOL_LOG_DROP_INVALID=0
```

`INVALID` is another state for packets, set by the kernel connection tracker.

The rest of the packets should be logged, since they will be the only indication that something is not working properly.

With firehol, you can set the rate of these logs. The default rate is this:

```
FIREHOL_LOG_FREQUENCY="1/second"
FIREHOL_LOG_BURST="5"
```

Set them to whatever you believe is right for you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed it, but now I still see items like this;


`Dec 22 16:31:07 ruby kernel: [458488.854790] IN-InetZiggo:IN=eth4 OUT= MAC=<mac> SRC=83.84.36.1 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=365 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=67 DPT=68 LEN=345`


I believe a portscan or such for a vulnerability. Since my policy is set to rejectt, I would not expect that being logged, since it's explicitly dropped.

Comment: This is a DHCP message. As you can see it goes to 255.255.255.255, which means: all the hosts in this LAN.

Comment: If you really want to prevent firehol from logging all these packets, you can add `server all reject` at the end of the interface (not the routers). I strongly suggest NOT to do it though. Packets you do not allow should be logged. Lower the frequency and/or use ULOGD to get them off your syslog, but leave them there. You are going to need them at some point.

Comment: Does `ACK-PSH-FIN` log is harmless? Or I should adjust some linux network stack setting?